# SharePoint Drop Down Menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am trying remove an item from the drop down menu. I recently linked the recycling bin to each of our plants, and now it is showing up in the drop down menu. I checked global navigation and had no luck. Please see the attached pictures for reference.[image: I need to remove this]

[image: Recycling bin is located here, note that none of the other elements shown here show up on the drop down menu]

Answer (score 1):

For the **Current Navigation**:

You can click **Edit Links** [image]  button on the page and click the **Delete** icon next the navigation link to delete the link you don’t need.

[image]

Another method, navigate to `Site settings > Look and Feel > Navigation`, select the link and click **Delete**.

[image]

For the **Global Navigation**:

I suppose that you are using the **Managed Navigation**.

Open the “**Term Store Management Tool** to edit term sets. Uncheck the **Show in Global Navigation Menu** for the “Recycling Bin …” term.

[image]